# empty object in category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I read Maclane's book recently.

- the product of empty product is terminal object.this make sense if use the universal definition.

in the category of finite products(this is equivalent to any two objects of the category has product).the book has said it had terminal object. Just take the product of two empty objects.

I am confused about the following:

-take two empty object,this means in category $C$of finite products,we can consider empty object as an object of $C$. this  make sense because empty object do not destroy the structure of any category.

- but if we consider the category of preorder $Z$($i\le j$ iff there is only one arrow from $i$ to $j$),then it has terminal object $+\infty$ and initial object $-\infty$.is this true?

Comment: I think you use the word "of" too often here. Are you sure you mean the category of finite products, rather than a category which has finite products?

Comment: Since $+\infty$ is not an object of that category, it simply cannot be the terminal object.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yeah ,my meaning is this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez but $Z$ has finite products

Comment: A terminal object of a catgory is an object of the category. Since $+\infty$ is not an object of $Z$, then it can be the terminal object of $Z$ just as much as my chair.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  you mean the category which has finite products has terminal objects is wrong?

Comment: @Sky - As I answer below, $\mathbb{Z}$ has *binary* products (resp. coproducts), not all finite products (resp. coproducts). The nonexistence of a greatest (resp. least) element tells you exactly this.

Comment: You can **easily** check that that category does not have a terminal object, just by using the definitions...

Comment: @MaliceVidrine it has all finite products:the greatest lower bound.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  yeah.So you mean the opinion in Maclane 'a book is not right?

Comment: @Sky - That's verifiably incorrect. It has those for *non-empty finite sets*. You can easily prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ has no greatest element for the same reason that you can prove $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine thank you!I confused for some days mainly because it seems that the classical category book has no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to check to be sure, but I doubt Mac Lane says to take the binary product of two "empty objects", which is nonsense. You take the finite product of the empty set of objects.

As Mariano states in the comments, $\mathbb{Z}$, as a preorder, has no initial or terminal object. $\mathbb{Z}$ does have *binary* products, and therefore products of arity $\geq 1$, but that's no guarantee that you get products of *zero* arity.